# How can I stick bathroom tiles back down?

Tags: bathroom, water, ceramic-tile

Some water got under the tiles and now they move around as you stand on them. How can I fix this, is there a way to stick them back down?

Comment: Has the grout cracked, and does the tile pull up from the thin-set?

Comment: Do you mean cracked underneath? to be honest I have not tried to lift them up, I just know that they move around so much that they are probably not stuck now at all.

Comment: What type of tile is it: ceramic or porcelain, stone, vinyl?

Comment: It's not vinyl, I have no idea what type it is because they were fitted before moving into the house.